# How to avoid Error in deploy with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Whenever I try to deploy my system the following error occurs:

```
root@:/var/www/code# bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /var/www/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/var/www/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `require'
```

I tried to make an update on all gems:

```
gem update
```

And I followed the "[Incompatible library version on Ubuntu 16.04](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1463#issuecomment-262280409)" issue, but yet it doesn't work.

Why does this happen?

I circled the uninstallation and installation code at the root of the project:

```
root@:/var/www/code# gem uninstall nokogiri
```

And then:

```
root@:/var/www/code# gem install nokogiri
```

My `gem list` shows:

```
root@:/var/www/code# gem list
- nokogiri (1.7.1)
```

But when I try to compile it appears again:

```
/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

Should I accomplish this within the `gems/` folder?

Comment: Try to `gem uninstall nokogiri` and install it again. It seems stupid but solved for me in the past

Comment: I was just trying to do this, I already answered if it worked

Comment: @AnezioCampos I posted more information than I tried

Comment: `gem uninstall nokogiri && gem install nokogiri && rm -rf Gemfile.lock && bundle` might help.

Comment: What's your output for `bundle install`?

Comment: `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` KILL IT WITH FIRE

Comment: I had upgraded the gems, I believe that they needed to bundle all of them in the project with bundle install, but somehow. `gem update` was not enough to update the nokogiri, so I had to uninstall and reinstall the gem,